# MYSQL trigger will not be created due to error

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a trigger in MYSQL 5.0.95 that prevents an insert from happening when an @ sign isn't found in in the email field. I know there are other ways of doing this other than triggers but I really want to learn how triggers work

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerUsersEmail 
BEFORE INSERT ON Users 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (Users.email NOT LIKE '%@%') THEN
DECLARE dummy INT;
SELECT not a valid email address INTO dummy FROM Users WHERE 1=1
END IF;
END;$$
```

I run the above with a delimiter of $$ in PHPMYADMIN but I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE dummy INT; SELECT not a valid email address INTO dummy FROM Users WHERE' at line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried this?

```
    CREATE TRIGGER triggerUsersEmail 
    BEFORE INSERT ON Users 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE dummy INT;
    IF (Users.email NOT LIKE '%@%') THEN
    SELECT not a valid email address INTO dummy FROM Users WHERE 1=1
    END IF;
    END;$$
```

Declare variables after begin.

_*_* Edit

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggerUsersEmail 
BEFORE INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE dummy INT;

    IF (Users.email NOT LIKE '%@%') THEN
        SELECT "not a valid email address" INTO dummy FROM Users WHERE 1=1;
    END IF;
END;

$$
```

This worked on my server

Comment: Now I get "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'email address INTO dummy FROM Users WHERE 1=1 END IF; END' at line 7"

Comment: Actually i didnt get what you want with this select query. it seems very wrong :) can you share your users table and tell us what you want to do

Comment: MYSQL 5.0 doesn't have SIGNAL so I'm trying to stop the INSERT from happening by throwing my own error. Even if I change the " SELECT not a valid email address INTO dummy FROM Users WHERE 1=1" to something valid like "SET NEW.email = '5@5.com'" it still throws the same error.   My Users table is http://pastebin.com/Nvtx9Vhy

Comment: can you try to select your message with quotes

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF; END' at line 8

Comment: I created user table with your code and it worked for me. I edited my answer

Comment: I connected via command line and ran it and it worked, thanks :)